# Setting a default featured image in a plugins code

Tags: image, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-featured-image

Following on from an earlier post, the below code is part of Keyring Social Importer, and it imports my Tweets from Twitter and posts them as individual blog posts on my self-installed website.

How I could make it set the featured image of all of the blog posts it creates to something?

Currently it just imports my Tweets as publishes them as blog posts, no images whatsoever. But my theme relies heavily on featured images and thumbnails, so I'd like to know how to set it programmatically.

```
<?php

function Keyring_Twitter_Importer() {

class Keyring_Twitter_Importer extends Keyring_Importer_Base {
    const SLUG              = 'twitter';    // e.g. 'twitter' (should match a service in Keyring)
    const LABEL             = 'Twitter';    // e.g. 'Twitter'
    const KEYRING_SERVICE   = 'Keyring_Service_Twitter';    // Full class name of the Keyring_Service this importer requires
    const REQUESTS_PER_LOAD = 3;     // How many remote requests should be made before reloading the page?

    var $auto_import = false;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        add_action( 'keyring_importer_twitter_custom_options', array( $this, 'custom_options' ) );
    }

    function custom_options() {
        ?><tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row">
                <label for="include_rts"><?php _e( 'Import retweets', 'keyring' ); ?></label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="include_rts" id="include_rts"<?php echo checked( $this->get_option( 'include_rts', true ) ); ?> />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row">
                <label for="include_replies"><?php _e( 'Import @replies', 'keyring' ); ?></label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="include_replies" id="include_replies"<?php echo checked( $this->get_option( 'include_replies', true ) ); ?> />
            </td>
        </tr><?php
    }

    function handle_request_options() {
        // Validate options and store them so they can be used in auto-imports
        if ( empty( $_POST['category'] ) || !ctype_digit( $_POST['category'] ) )
            $this->error( __( "Make sure you select a valid category to import your checkins into." ) );

        if ( empty( $_POST['author'] ) || !ctype_digit( $_POST['author'] ) )
            $this->error( __( "You must select an author to assign to all checkins." ) );

        if ( isset( $_POST['auto_import'] ) )
            $_POST['auto_import'] = true;
        else
            $_POST['auto_import'] = false;

        if ( isset( $_POST['include_rts'] ) )
            $_POST['include_rts'] = true;
        else
            $_POST['include_rts'] = false;

        if ( isset( $_POST['include_replies'] ) )
            $_POST['include_replies'] = true;
        else
            $_POST['include_replies'] = false;

        // If there were errors, output them, otherwise store options and start importing
        if ( count( $this->errors ) ) {
            $this->step = 'greet';
        } else {
            $this->set_option( array(
                'category'        => (int) $_POST['category'],
                'tags'            => explode( ',', $_POST['tags'] ),
                'author'          => (int) $_POST['author'],
                'include_replies' => (bool) $_POST['include_replies'],
                'include_rts'     => (bool) $_POST['include_rts'],
                'auto_import'     => (bool) $_POST['auto_import'],
                'user_id'         => $this->service->get_token()->get_meta( 'user_id' ),
            ) );

            $this->step = 'import';
        }
    }

    function build_request_url() {
        // Base request URL
        $url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?";
        $params = array(
            'user_id' => $this->get_option( 'user_id' ),
            'trim_user' => 'true',
            'count' => 75, // More than this and Twitter seems to get flaky
            'include_entities' => 'true',
        );
        if ( false == $this->get_option( 'include_replies' ) )
            $params['exclude_replies'] = 'true';
        if ( true == $this->get_option( 'include_rts' ) )
            $params['include_rts'] = 'true';
        $url = $url . http_build_query( $params );


        if ( $this->auto_import ) {
            // Locate our most recently imported Tweet, and get ones since then
            $latest = get_posts( array(
                'numberposts' => 1,
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'meta_key'    => 'keyring_service', // In case there are other asides
                'meta_value'  => 'twitter',
                'tax_query' => array( array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array( 'post-format-standard' ), // Tweets stored as asides
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                ) ),
            ) );

            // If we have already imported some, then start since the most recent
            if ( $latest ) {
                $max = get_post_meta( $latest[0]->ID, 'twitter_id', true );
                $url = add_query_arg( 'since_id', $max, $url );
            }
        } else {
            // Handle page offsets (only for non-auto-import requests)
            $url = add_query_arg( 'page', $this->get_option( 'page', 0 ), $url );
        }

        return $url;
    }

    function extract_posts_from_data( $raw ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $importdata = $raw;

        if ( null === $importdata ) {
            $this->finished = true;
            return new Keyring_Error( 'keyring-twitter-importer-failed-download', __( 'Failed to download your tweets from Twitter. Please wait a few minutes and try again.', 'keyring' ) );
        }

        // Check for API overage/errors
        if ( !empty( $importdata->error ) ) {
            $this->finished = true;
            return new Keyring_Error( 'keyring-twitter-importer-throttled', __( 'You have made too many requests to Twitter and have been temporarily blocked. Please try again in 1 hour (duplicate tweets will be skipped).', 'keyring' ) );
        }

        // Make sure we have some tweets to parse
        if ( !is_array( $importdata ) || !count( $importdata ) ) {
            $this->finished = true;
            return;
        }

        // Get the total number of tweets we're importing
        if ( !empty( $importdata[0]->user->statuses_count ) )
            $this->set_option( 'total', $importdata[0]->user->statuses_count );

        // Parse/convert everything to WP post structs
        foreach ( $importdata as $post ) {
            // Double-check for @replies, which shouldn't be included at all if we chose to skip them
            if ( true == $this->get_option( 'exclude_replies' ) && null != $post->in_reply_to_screen_name )
                continue;

            // Post title can be empty for Asides, but it makes them easier to manage if they have *something*
            $title_words = explode( ' ', strip_tags( $post->text ) );
            $post_title  = implode( ' ', array_slice( $title_words, 0, 15 ) );
// Use the first 15 words
            if ( count( $title_words ) > 15 )
                $post_title .= '&hellip;'; 


            // Parse/adjust dates
            $post_date_gmt = strtotime( $post->created_at );
            $post_date_gmt = gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $post_date_gmt );
            $post_date     = get_date_from_gmt( $post_date_gmt );

            // Apply selected category
            $post_category = array( $this->get_option( 'category' ) );

            // Clean up content a bit
            $post_content = $post->text;
            $post_content = $wpdb->escape( html_entity_decode( trim( $post_content ) ) );

            // Handle entities supplied by Twitter
            if ( count( $post->entities->urls ) ) {
                foreach ( $post->entities->urls as $url ) {
                    $post_content = str_replace( $url->url, $url->expanded_url, $post_content );
                }
            }

            // Any hashtags used in a tweet will be applied to the Post as tags in WP
            $tags = $this->get_option( 'tags' );
            if ( preg_match_all( '/(^|[(\[\s])#(\w+)/', $post_content, $tag ) )
                $tags = array_merge( $tags, $tag[2] );

            // Add HTML links to URLs, usernames and hashtags
            $post_content = make_clickable( esc_html( $post_content ) );

            // Include geo Data (if provided by Twitter)
            if ( !empty( $post->geo ) && 'point' == strtolower( $post->geo->type ) )
                $geo = array(
                    'lat' => $post->geo->coordinates[0],
                    'long' => $post->geo->coordinates[1]
                );
            else
                $geo = array();

            // Get a GUID from Twitter, plus other important IDs to store in postmeta later
            $user = $this->service->get_token()->get_meta( 'username' );
            $twitter_id              = $post->id_str;
            $twitter_permalink       = "https://twitter.com/{$user}/status/{$twitter_id}";
            $in_reply_to_user_id     = $post->in_reply_to_user_id;
            $in_reply_to_screen_name = $post->in_reply_to_screen_name;
            $in_reply_to_status_id   = $post->in_reply_to_status_id;
            $post_author             = $this->get_option( 'author' );
            $post_status             = 'publish';
            $twitter_raw             = $post;

            // Build the post array, and hang onto it along with the others
            $this->posts[] = compact(
                'post_author',
                'post_date',
                'post_date_gmt',
                'post_content',
                'post_title',
                'post_status',
                'post_category',
                'tags',
                'twitter_id',
                'twitter_permalink',
                'geo',
                'in_reply_to_user_id',
                'in_reply_to_screen_name',
                'in_reply_to_status_id',
                'twitter_raw'
            );
        }
    }

    function insert_posts() {
        global $wpdb;
        $imported = 0;
        $skipped  = 0;
        foreach ( $this->posts as $post ) {
            extract( $post );
            if (
                $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT meta_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key = 'twitter_id' AND meta_value = %s", $twitter_id ) )
            ||
                $post_id = post_exists( $post_title, $post_content, $post_date )
            ) {
                // Looks like a duplicate
                $skipped++;
            } else {
                $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );

                if ( is_wp_error( $post_id ) )
                    return $post_id;

                if ( !$post_id )
                    continue;


                // Track which Keyring service was used
                add_post_meta( $post_id, 'keyring_service', $this->service->get_name() );

                // Store the twitter id, reply ids etc
                add_post_meta( $post_id, 'twitter_id', $twitter_id );
                add_post_meta( $post_id, 'twitter_permalink', $twitter_permalink );
                if ( !empty( $in_reply_to_user_id ) )
                    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'twitter_in_reply_to_user_id', $in_reply_to_user_id );
                if ( !empty( $in_reply_to_screen_name ) )
                    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'twitter_in_reply_to_screen_name', $in_reply_to_screen_name );
                if ( !empty( $in_reply_to_status_id ) )
                    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'twitter_in_reply_to_status_id', $in_reply_to_status_id );

                // Update Category and Tags
                wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $post_category );
                if ( count( $tags ) )
                    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, implode( ',', $tags ) );

                // Store geodata if it's available
                if ( !empty( $geo ) ) {
                    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'geo_latitude', $geo['lat'] );
                    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'geo_longitude', $geo['long'] );
                    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'geo_public', 1 );
                }

                add_post_meta( $post_id, 'raw_import_data', json_encode( $twitter_raw ) );

                $imported++;
            }
        }
        $this->posts = array();

        // Return, so that the handler can output info (or update DB, or whatever)
        return array( 'imported' => $imported, 'skipped' => $skipped );
    }
}

} // end function Keyring_Twitter_Importer


add_action( 'init', function() {
    Keyring_Twitter_Importer(); // Load the class code from above
    keyring_register_importer(
        'twitter',
        'Keyring_Twitter_Importer',
        plugin_basename( __FILE__ ),
        __( 'Import all of your tweets from Twitter as Posts (marked as "asides") in WordPress.', 'keyring' )
    );
} );
```

Comment: i think you must hire some1 ;)

Comment: Well, you simply pasted 300 lines of code and expect full analysis and solution to your request? You need to focus on the `insert_posts` function and its `add_post_meta` calls. If you research here or in [wordpress.se], you'll find the post meta key name for the Featured Images. ::: Can you provide the link to this "earlier post" you mention?

Comment: It's OK, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for anyone who's interested. Just have to add the below "New Line" in in the specified place:

```
  }

        add_post_meta( $post_id, 'raw_import_data', json_encode( $twitter_raw ) );

        // NEW LINE (change 1001 to the image ID):
        set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 1001 );

        $imported++;
    }
```